# rich:autocomplete rerendering labels

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jboss6.x

I have 2 fields in a jsf form. Field 1 uses rich:autocomplete, and field 2 uses inputText.  I type invalid data in field 2 so that the validation message appears.  Next, I start typing in field 1.  As soon as I do this, the validation message in field 2 disappears. How can I prevent this?

```
<h:outputLabel value="Field 1:" escape="false"/>
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                                <rich:autocomplete id="id1" mode="ajax" showButton="false"
                                                                        autocompleteMethod="#{bean.method}"
                                                                        autocompleteList="#{bean.aList}"  
                                                                        value="#{bean.field}"
                                                                        required="true"
                                                                        requiredMessage="Field 1 required">                
                                                         <a4j:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" bypassUpdates="#{true}" render="id1,id1Msg" />
                                        </rich:autocomplete>
                                        <rich:message for="id1" id="id1Msg" />
                                </h:panelGroup>



<h:outputLabel for="id2" value="Field 2:"/>
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                        <h:inputText id="id2" value="#{bean.field2}" style="width: 175px;" required="true" requiredMessage="Field 2 required" validatorMessage="Field 2 Please enter digits only" converterMessage="Field 2 - Please enter digits only">
                                                <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"  bypassUpdates="#{true}" render="id2Msg"/>
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <rich:message for="id2" id="id2Msg"/>  
                                </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `execute="@form"` on `id2`. This will cause `id2` to always trigger the submission of the entire form, even when it loses focus, causing the validation message to appear

`execute="@this"` on `id2` as it stands means that only the parent component will be triggered

Comment: Tried: Set execute="@form" on id2 but behaviour was the same.

Comment: I got the desired behaviour by using execute="@form" on id1.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired behaviour by using execute="@form" on id1.